# What is a more efficient way to subset a dictionary of numpy arrays or a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have written a MWE to try to summarize my problem. If I have 8 NumPy arrays and I want to filter each of them based on conditions related to all of the arrays, what is a more efficient way to achieve this (with respect to memory/speed)?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

# data generation
data = dict()
for key in ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]:
  data[key] = np.random.rand(1000000)
```

Attempt #1:

```
start = time.perf_counter()

validmask = (data["a"] > 0.2) & (data["b"] < 0.8) & (data["c"] > 0.5) & (data["d"] > 0.9) & (data["e"] < 0.9) & (data["f"] < 0.8) & (data["g"] > 0.1) & (data["h"] > 0.5)

validdata = dict()
for key in data.keys():
  validdata[key] = data[key][validmask]

print(f"time = {time.perf_counter()-start}")
```

Yields `time = 0.028449237000018`.

Attempt #2:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for key in data.keys():
  df[key] = data[key]

start = time.perf_counter()
df[(df["a"] > 0.2) & (df["b"] < 0.8) & (df["c"] > 0.5) & (df["d"] > 0.9) & (df["e"] < 0.9) & (df["f"] < 0.8) & (df["g"] > 0.1) & (df["h"] > 0.5)]
print(f"time = {time.perf_counter()-start}")
```

Yields `time = 0.08374083499995777`.

Comment: The important question is: *I have 8 NumPy* of the same length?

Comment: can you have equality as comparison operation, or at least not strict inequality like `data["a"] >= 0.2`?

Comment: @Corralien yes, they are all of the same length.

Comment: @Ben.T yes, `>=` or `<=` is fine!